# Google appengine ReferenceProperty is None

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Google App Engine models, like so:

```
class Letter(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class Word(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    letter = db.ReferenceProperty(Letter)
```

Then I try insert word to database manually. I write `"http://localhost:8000"` and "datastore Viewer". I choose Word table, but I could'nt choose Letter, because there is "None" near the letter. Like this:

```
Word
letter (None)
name (string)
```

I can save word database but not with "letter property". Letter property is none everytime. Where am I wrong?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're seeing `None` when you're trying to manually add a new `Word` in the datastore viewer? Do you have any `Letter` values added yet? If not, the `ReferenceProperty` will have no legal values.

Comment: Yes, I have Letter value  :(( And you understood correctly, thanks, what can I do?

Comment: Why there is "None"  near the letter, I couldnt figure out this ?

Comment: On a separate note, you should look into using the `ndb` module, as opposed to the plain `db` here.

Answer (score 0):

A ReferenceProperty is essentially a Key to another Entity.  The datastore admin doesn't have the interface to create another entity (your Letter) entity from your Word entity.

Essentially you can't do this through the Admin page.  Consider using the a local python shell and the remote api to do this https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi#Running_Remote_Shell

Another option might be the interactive console.  There's some steps to set that up though, there's probably some other stackoverflow question that describes how.